# WP7 saving multiple entries on different lines from Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am taking information from a form, saving it to isolated storage and building a list of the different entries on a separate page. I can display the text of the first data entry but simply can't figure out how to continue to store them in the same file.

This is my Form Page:

```
        var multipleStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string multipleFile = "multipleFile.txt";
        using (var file = multipleStorage.OpenFile(multipleFile, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                writer.Write(nameTextBox.Text + ", " + dunsTextBox.Text + ", " + typeCheck + ", " + resellerCheck + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

And this is my receiving page:

```
    private void resultTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("multipleFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                resultTextBlock.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a good usage of IsolatedStorage. IsolatedStorage is designed to have information saved after you've exited the app. As such, saving information to disk can be very time-consuming.

A better way to do this would be 
**1:.** Have a global object/class/etc. Such as in 
App.xaml.cs have a object like:

```
public static Dictionary<string,object> myPageContextObjects;
```

and on your page, add the items you need to pass:

```
App.myPageContextObjects.Add("nameTextBox.Text",nameTextBox.Text);
...
```

Or **2:**, you can use the querystring method. When navigating to anew page, add the info into the URI. Such as

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new URI("mypage.xaml" + "?nameTextBox.Text=" + nameTextBox.Text + "&dunsTextBox.Text=" + dunsTextBox.Text....) ).
```

When you're on the new page, overload the OnNavigatedTo Method to access the string.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string selected = String.Empty;

        //check to see if the selected parameter was passed.
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("selected"))
        {
            //get the selected parameter off the query string from MainPage.
            selected = NavigationContext.QueryString["selected"];
        }
}
```

I made a quick solution earlier that demonstrates a simple example of passing information across pages. You can download it here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/Panorama_querystring.zip

Comment: Thank you for the reply and I understand these other methods of passing data, but I actually am in need of demonstrating Isolated Storage for an assignment that I am working on.

Comment: Sure. Well, If you aren't set on using a stream, you can do it like this:

Comment: I am passing the data fine between the pages and storing it, but when I go back to add another set of information on the home page it just replaces the first set on the destination page. I am trying to create a list.

Comment: //
        // Summary:
        //     Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates
        //     a new file. System.IO.FileMode.Append can only be used in conjunction with
        //     System.IO.FileAccess.Write. Attempting to seek to a position before the end
        //     of the file will throw an System.IO.IOException and any attempt to read fails
        //     and throws an System.NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add to the file, you need to use the `System.IO.FileMode.Append` property.

```
 var multipleStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    string multipleFile = "multipleFile.txt";
    using (var file = multipleStorage.OpenFile(multipleFile, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            writer.Write(nameTextBox.Text + ", " + dunsTextBox.Text + ", " + typeCheck + ", " + resellerCheck + System.Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```